# Androidannotation with Android Studio 0.5+, gradle 0.9+, android-apt plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-annotations

Found problem while compiling project using Androidannotation with Android Studio 0.5+, gradle 0.9+, android-apt (http://www.jayway.com/2014/02/21/androidannotations-setup-in-android-studio/) plugin:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/codemodel/JExpression;

There is problem with JExpression in jdk7, i think it was moved to another package: com.sun.codemodel.internal.*

I have resolved this problem by downloading jaxb-xjc-2.2.6.jar (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaxbxjc226jar.htm) and importing it to the project (via gradle dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

One more solution was found:
in build.gradle i changed this
`compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0.1@jar'`
`compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0.1@jar'`

to this:
`compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0.+'`
`compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0.+'`

And it works!